# C++ CreateProcess with arguments deadlock

Tags: c++, deadlock, createprocess

I have two applications (exe).

The first one (`client.exe`) just prints out the arguments:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::cout << "Have " << argc << " arguments:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) 
    {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The second one (`SandBox.exe`) executes the first one with some arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void startup(LPCTSTR lpApplicationName, LPSTR param)
{
    // additional information
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // set the size of the structures
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // start the program up
    CreateProcess(lpApplicationName,   // the path
        param,//NULL,//argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}

int main()
{
    startup(TEXT("client.exe"), TEXT("client.exe thisIsMyFirstParaMeter AndTheSecond"));
    return 0;
}
```

By executing the `client.exe` from the `SandBox.exe`, the output is very strange, and the **client.exe never ends and stays in a deadlock**.

[image]

What is the problem here?

I was expecting some output like (like when I run the `client.exe` isolated):

[image]

Thank you

Comment: How do you know it is a deadlock?

Comment: The second parameter to `CreateProcess` must point to a mutable string, AFAIK.

Comment: What happens if you wait for client process end using `WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );` before handle closing in `main()`?

Comment: That's it @vasek :) Can you write that as an answer so I can close this thread please?

Comment: Just to be explicit: the `client.exe` _does_ end in the original version (it's final `d` can be seen prior to the `C:\>` prompt) the problem is that because the parent process exits immediately without waiting, the client's output is getting mixed in with the command-window's output. You would probably see something similar if the parent process was to print some text as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controlling application should wait until the client exits. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

```
// start the program up
CreateProcess(lpApplicationName,   // the path
    param,          // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
);

// Wait until child process exits.
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE ); // <--- this

// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```